# Where can I find Spring.NET documentation?

Tags: .net, spring, spring.net

Is there any working documentation for Spring.NET, as website, files, working sources?
[Documentation on official site](https://www.springframework.net/documentation.html) throws 5XX errors in most places.
[Documentation from GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net) is not buildable.
[Official forum](https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/06/legacy-forums-will-be-shutdown-february-28) linking to StackOverflow as new place to ask questions.

Comment: The fact that it is mostly dormant for the past 10 years, should be an indication about the state of the project.

Answer (score 0):

The change log at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/blob/main/changelog.txt shows the last version was released in Aug 2021.

However, it looks like not much is happening with the project.  I was looking to get a newer version that would work with the latest log4net version and it seems Spring.Net is a few years behind log4net.

The git repo is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net

Based on their lack of response in stackoverflow, I don't have much hope for spring.net